# Auto import in Vscode not working in React Native project

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, auto-import

I am using [Auto Import](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport) plugin in React Native project but I am not getting any suggestions while typing any elements like button or view.

However it is working with other frameworks like Angular or any other.